# Is it possible to own more than one ship at the same time?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I never bought a ship in this game. When I do, will I forfeit my old ship always? Or can I store it so I can switch it depending on the mission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to own more than one ship at a time, however it can be a hassle switching between them. When you buy a new ship, your current ship is stored *at that station*. It will remain there, ready for you to pick it up, but you must return to that station to do so.

For example, say I purchased a Viper from Ngaliba, storing my Hauler there. Then, I fly 120+ LY away and discover an amazingly profitable trade route. My options would be to either fly *back* to Ngaliba to pick up my Hauler, or just purchase a new Hauler.

Comment: Extra hassle: You cannot change ships while you have cargo (even if it would fit in the new ship).

Comment: Update in 2018: You can now transfer ships between stations for a fee (you have to be at the destination), and you can transfer cargo between ships.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can store as many ships as you want. They'll be stored in the station you buy your new ship in. When buying a new ship you're given two options:

- Sell current ship to partially pay for new ship.
- Store current ship and buy new ship at full cost.